# Python: Deleting Specific value from the list

Tags: python, list, function, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let say if

```
# Displaying old and reference in columns for better visual #

old=      [2,2,6,6,2,4, 6, 6, 8,2]
reference=[7,1,6,2,4,9,10,16,12,5]
ID=2
```

What is faster way to remove the variable ID from reference list and delete 
old[ reference[ID match] ] from the old list?

I happens to developed this solution while asking my question... but is there better way to do this?

```
def List_Value_Removal(old,reference,ID):
    counter=0
    new=[]
    for test in reference:
        if ID!=test:
           new.append(old[counter])
        checker+=1
    return new
```

Comment: Ugh! I used Array Again! Fixing it now

Comment: you mean `if ID!=test` there?

Comment: Yes, Editted to show that

Comment: You have `counter` and `checker`; I suspect the latter should be called `counter` too. Also, you probably meant `new.append(old[counter])` here (square brackets to index into `old`).

Comment: Ah, I missed that as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up the lists, then a list comprehension to only *keep* values where the reference value does not match `ID`:

```
def List_Value_Removal(old, reference, ID):
    return [v for v, ref in zip(old, reference) if ref != ID]

 values, references = List_Value_Removal(values, references, some_id)
```

Demo:

```
>>> old = [2, 2, 6, 6, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 2]
>>> reference = [7, 1, 6, 2, 4, 9, 10, 16, 12, 5]
>>> ID = 2
>>> [v for v, ref in zip(old, reference) if ref != ID]
[2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 2]
```

If you need to update `reference` as well, return two lists:

```
def List_Value_Removal(old, reference, ID):
    return zip(*((v, ref) for v, ref in zip(old, reference) if ref != ID))
```

Demo:

```
>>> new, newref = zip(*((v, ref) for v, ref in zip(old, reference) if ref != ID))
>>> new
(2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 2)
>>> newref
(7, 1, 6, 4, 9, 10, 16, 12, 5)
```

Comment: This is one good solution to do it. Does you know any other ways to do it as well?

Comment: This is the best way. You could use `enumerate()` instead of `counter` in your method, but the list comprehension is going to win it on speed anyway.

Comment: @Bugboy1028 Sorry, do you need to remove those entries from the reference list then?

Comment: @Roberto, does rest of the answer to my question and comments gave you the answer to your question? If not, please clarify.

Comment: Does this answer applied to Python 2.7.x as well?

Comment: Hello @Bugboy1028, I'm fine, I'm just curious about this timing thing but no worry, I'll figure it out :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
old=      [2,2,6,6,2,4,6,6,8,2]
reference=[7,1,6,2,4,9,10,16,12,5]
ID=2

new = [old[i] for i in range(len(old)) if reference[i] != ID]
```

Comment: Why not use `[v for i, v in enumerate(old) if reference[i] != ID]`? But the `zip()` version is more efficient because it doesn't have to have an additional item lookup.

Comment: That's nice, but is it just equivalent or better for some reason?

Comment: It is faster; try it with `timeit`.

Comment: Cool!Heh you replied even before I asked

Comment: What is timeit, @MartijnPieters ?

Comment: Interesting! So with timeit, zip is much faster than both, and my solution is slower. But with this script, enumerate is the fastest, and zip is slower than my chubby solution... I have, of course, no idea. But timeit isn't timing like a "real" script here...?
http://pastebin.com/YwfrJZh0

Comment: I mean, if I understood well you mean that `zip` will give both reference and old values at once, with no need for an `i`, so it should save time. And it makes sense. But I don't know why it's faster with timeit but slower with that script.

Answer (score 0):

Just considering both the list are of same length and only one index to remove, btw we can make it more generic :

```
>>> old = [2,2,6,6,2,4, 6, 6, 8,2]
>>> reference=[7,1,6,2,4,9,10,16,12,5]
>>> id = 2
>>> del old[(reference.index(id))]
>>> old
[2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 6, 6, 8, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: This only works if there is only **one** occurence of `ID` in `reference. If there are 0 or more than 1, this will not work correctly.

Comment: Actually, no. If I do this way, it will delete first value it saw

Comment: @MartijnPieters, reference will exactly one value for one id... say if you are doing ID=10 , it will delete value of 6 from ID=6 instead of ID=10 value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def List_Value_Removal(old,ref, id):
    new = old[:]
    ind = ref.index(id)
    new.pop(ind)
    return new
```

Not sure if there is a particular reason that you are using two arrays?
If you used a dict:

```
ref = {7:2,1:2,6:6,2:6,4:2,9:4,10:6,16:6,12:8,5:2}
```

You could just:

```
ref.pop(id)
```

Comment: Why does this function doesn't have return? Global and Local variables is separated. This function will return None for varible new that I gave you. I didn't meant to use arrays at all in this question.